# Как сделать фокус в выпадающем меню при tab?

Tags: html, css

```
<ul class="main-menu">
          <li class="main-menu-catalog main-menu-item">
            <a href="blank.html" class="main-menu-link">Каталог товаров</a>         
            <ul class="catalog-menu">
              <li><a href="blank.html">Виртуальная реальность</a></li>
              <li><a href="catalog.html">Моноподы для селфи</a></li>
              <li><a href="blank.html">Экшн-камеры</a></li>
              <li><a href="blank.html">Фитнес-браслеты</a></li>
              <li class="catalog-new-line"><a href="blank.html">Умные часы</a></li>
              <li><a href="blank.html">Квадрокоптеры</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="main-menu-delivery main-menu-item"><a href="blank.html" class="main-menu-link">Доставка</a></li>
          <li class="main-menu-guarantee main-menu-item"><a href="blank.html" class="main-menu-link">Гарантия</a></li>
          <li class="main-menu-contact main-menu-item"><a href="blank.html" class="main-menu-link">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
```

catalog-menu это меню которое открывается. Вопрос в том, что при tab нужно, что бы фокус попадал на пункты меню. Как это сделать? Если по фокусу на main-menu-link открывать меню - таб все равно на него не попадает. Пробовал .main-menu-link:focus + .catalog-menu:focus-within, просто catalog-menu:focus-within, не работает

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял вопрос, то вот. Если нет, то сообщите об этом. Ответ будет удален.

```css
.main-menu a:focus {outline: red solid 2px;}
```

```html
<ul class="main-menu">
          <li class="main-menu-catalog main-menu-item">
            <a href="blank.html" class="main-menu-link">Каталог товаров</a>         
            <ul class="catalog-menu">
              <li><a href="blank.html">Виртуальная реальность</a></li>
              <li><a href="catalog.html">Моноподы для селфи</a></li>
              <li><a href="blank.html">Экшн-камеры</a></li>
              <li><a href="blank.html">Фитнес-браслеты</a></li>
              <li class="catalog-new-line"><a href="blank.html">Умные часы</a></li>
              <li><a href="blank.html">Квадрокоптеры</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="main-menu-delivery main-menu-item"><a href="blank.html" class="main-menu-link">Доставка</a></li>
          <li class="main-menu-guarantee main-menu-item"><a href="blank.html" class="main-menu-link">Гарантия</a></li>
          <li class="main-menu-contact main-menu-item"><a href="blank.html" class="main-menu-link">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: нужно, что бы tab попадал только на .catalog-menu?